# Display contact picture in outlook 2007 email

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook-2007

I just want to view the contact's picture in any emails I receive. Is there a way to enable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Microsoft's [Deploying additional registry values in the Office Customization Tool for Outlook 2007](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc837949%28office.12%29.aspx) :

> **Contact picture displayed in e-mail header**
>
> All e-mail messages received from a
>   contact for which you have a picture
>   will display the contact’s picture to
>   the right of the message header. To
>   disable this feature, deploy the
>   following registry data:

```
Key: HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlook\Options\Mail
DWORD: ShowContactPicture
Values:1 (or missing DWORD) = show contact picture if available
0 = do not show contact picture
```

So you might check that the value of this registry entry is 1, or try to delete it.

A somewhat conflicting information from Microsoft's [Add, change, or remove a picture for a contact](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/add-change-or-remove-a-picture-for-a-contact-HP010013779.aspx) :

> If both the sender and the recipient
>   are using Office Outlook 2007, a
>   contact picture is displayed in
>   messages received if the sender uses a
>   contact photo. The picture appears in
>   the message header [...] You can
>   double-click the contact picture to
>   open the contact or right-click it for
>   other contact options.
>
> Note : For the picture to display, the
>   contact must also be saved in an
>   Outlook Contact folder and that
>   Contact folder must be designated as
>   an Outlook Address Book (Outlook
>   Address Book: An address book that is
>   automatically created from contacts in
>   the Contacts folder. The contacts can
>   be people inside and outside of your
>   organization. When you update your
>   contacts, the Outlook Address Book is
>   updated as well.). These are the
>   default settings when creating
>   contacts in Microsoft Outlook. If you
>   don't see the picture included with a
>   contact, check to see if the default
>   settings have been changed.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is:

File > Options > Contacts

And uncheck the box next to "Show user photographs when available"

Ok and then restart Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook always shows a contact's picture when you open their mail. If you are not able to see one, make sure you have saved a picture of them in your Outlook contact list.

Answer (score 0):

Please download and install Microsoft Outlook Social Connector if you want to have the feature of MS Outlook 2010 (wherein you can see the sender's photo visible along side the sent mail) available within MS Outlook 2007 as well.